# Windows Python performance on repetetive calls

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python

I am using Windows 10 and have Python 2.7.12 installed and available in my PATH. The following sequence of powershell commands is run with very small delays between each other, but the very first command is ran after python.exe has not been invoked for a while:

```
PS C:\> (Measure-Command { & python.exe -c "pass" }).Milliseconds
382
PS C:\> (Measure-Command { & python.exe -c "pass" }).Milliseconds
46
PS C:\> (Measure-Command { & python.exe -c "pass" }).Milliseconds
34
PS C:\> (Measure-Command { & python.exe -c "pass" }).Milliseconds
32
PS C:\> (Measure-Command { & python.exe -c "pass" }).Milliseconds
33
```

If I wait for a couple of hours, the sequence if looking the same: slow first invocation and fast subsequent ones.

Why is the first invocation so much slower?

Comment: Because python needs to be loaded and/or PowerShell needs to setup stuff in order for Measure-Command to work.

Comment: File system cache, being discarded after a while, I'd say.

Comment: @ClassStacker: I have done an experiment just now: manually triggered a Windows Defender scan of the Python installation dir before running the command. IIUC, it should've populated the fs cache and also cached the AV-safety of the binary for some time. This had some effect on the initial invocation, but did not mitigate the effect entirely: it took 217 ms to run "pass".

Comment: @Seth: python needs to be loaded every time (bar FS caching effects) and I would expect that powershell setup time is not included in Measure-Command output.

Comment: Delayed loading of DLLs?

Comment: @ClassStacker: I am not sure what you mean by delayed loading of DLLs.